# Couldn't login using google on server but works fine on localhost

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I have integrated google calendar in which client needs to login to their google account first.
Everything works fine on local host but on server redirection for google account is not happening. I tried to look for this issue and have found some solution but couldn't undestand and implement that on my end that works on server.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python

This is the main code that is used for google sign in:

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('google_calendar_client_python.json', self.scope)
self.creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

Now I understand that there is some issue in "flow.run_local_server(port=0)" that works only on local host but I couldn't find any solution for this to make it work on server

Please help if you can.

P.S: Will post full code if anybody wants that!

Comment: How are you running it "on server"? I assume that locally you run the file in terminal and this "redirection" is just prompting you with your browser. If you're on ssh on your server, it cannot launch browser. If your server doesn't have gui, it cannot launch browser. Is that it?

Comment: I am saving the token value in the database not in a file. That should work fine on server, right?

Comment: No. You still don't have gui to launch the browser. As I said, the script wants to (locally) launch a browser to let the user log in. You're on a server, there's no gui apps unless you're rdp into windows server instead of ssh to any other server.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no knowledge on how to do this. Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Again: you can't. This lib is not meant to be used on server, it's to be used locally. Your server cannot make a browser window appear on your computer. When run on server, the code tries to open the browser there (on server) and fails. That's all.

Comment: Great, so google has not given any document for server calling. Anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: No. The docs are complete, the lib is just designed for local use (e.g. making your own desktop app that uses calendar). If you want "server calling", then use oauth dedicated for websites, not local apps.

Answer (score 1):

InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('google_calendar_client_python.json is intended for installed applications it opens the web consent form on the machine the code is running on.

it won't work hosted as it's going to open it on the web server.   You need to use web authentication code I normally use flask personally

yes the google python client supports it its just not very well documented